# Ambious overload after referencing Mvc.TagHelpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

After I've added the reference for the tag helpers in the razor views, following this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1266/using-tag-helpers-aspnetmvc-6-core-1).

The issue the reference add another method that has the same signature and at the end the compiler doesn't know which signature to choose, telling me that I have an ambiguous call.

[image]

I've added to my project.json file the following dependencies:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Razor": "4.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc":"1.0.0-rc1-final"

//And this is the code where I'm getting the error:
services.Configure<AppOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.ApiHost = "http://localhost:2934/";
});
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial seems to reference ASP.NET Core 1 RC1. In RC2 they changed quite a lot of stuff including namespaces and assemblies, renamed AspNet to AspNetCore, e.g. `Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor` is now `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools`. I guess you are mixing RC1 assemblies with RC2.
For a start just remove all dependencies that include the .AspNet. and rc1 words and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked, actually the reference was already there!